# Rails group by first column and then second column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, group-by

I have a Team model that has two attributes, `.type` and `.sub type`.

I would like to organize them in a call by `team.type` first and then `team.subtype`.

I tried

```
  Team.all.group_by{|e| [e.type, e.sub_type]}
```

But that gets me

```
{
  ["Sport", "Football"] => [
                            teamObject,
                            teamObject
                           ],
  ["Sport", "Soccer"] => [
                            teamObject,
                            teamObject
                           ],
}
```

What I want is....

```
{
 "Sport" => {
              "Football" => [ 
                              teamObject, 
                              teamObject
                            ],
              "Soccer" => [
                             teamObject,
                             teamObject
                            ],
            },
 "Drama" => {
              "Band" => [ teamObject, teamObject],
              "Dance" => [ teamObject, teamObject],
            },        
}
```

What should my query or filter look like?  Ideally, I would like to turn this into a scope.

Note:  I do not want to create more models, tables, or relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
Team.all.
     group_by { |e| e.type }.
     map { |k, v| [k, v.group_by { |e| e.sub_type }].to_h }
```

Or:

```
Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] } }.tap do |hash|
  Team.all.each { |t| hash[t.type][t.sub_type] << t }
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  I used     Team.all.group_by { |e| e.type }.map { |k, v| { k => v.group_by { |e| e.sub_type } } } .  How would I write as a scope?

Comment: You cannot write this as a scope. Scopes in Rails act on `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects and are supposed to generate SQL queries that run against the database. But the `group_by` method is called on the result array after that data was received from the database. You will always have to load the data from the database first, before you can group it with this method. You could write your own `nested_group_by` method on Array...